.Net/C# Unit Testing problem with EF Junction Tabel
I have a many to many relation between my two entities so the EF generated to me the junction tabel correctly and my code logic works fine but when i arrive to implement my unit tests i got a problem saying that :
System.InvalidOperationException : The property 'ClientTypeEntityDocumentsToProvideEntity (Dictionary<string, object>).Id' could not be found. Ensure that the property exists and has been included in the model.
so i don't figure out how to fix this issue .
these are my two entities :
   public class ClientTypeEntity : AEntity
 {
     /// <remarks>Fr :Nom type client.</remarks>
     public string TypeName { get; set; }

     /// <remarks>Fr : liste des dossier.</remarks>
     public ICollection<FolderEntity> Folders { get; set; }


     /// <remarks>Fr : liste des pièces á fournir.</remarks>
     public ICollection<DocumentsToProvideEntity> ClientTypeDocuments { get; set; }
 }


      public class DocumentsToProvideEntity : AEntity
  {
      /// <remarks>Fr : Nom document.</remarks>
      public string DocumentName { get; set; }

      /// <remarks>Fr : Nom document.</remarks>
      public string DocumentDescription { get; set; }

      /// <remarks>Fr : Type client.</remarks>
      public ICollection<ClientTypeEntity> ClientTypes { get; set; }

and this is my Repository test method :
     [Test]
    public async Task GetAll_WhenHaveEntities_ShouldReturnAsync()
    {
        // Arrange
        var dataTestService = new DataTestService();
    
        var modelInput = ClientTypeMock.GetClientType();
        var expectedModel = ClientTypeMock.GetAllClientType();
        var clientTypeRepository = new ClientTypesRepository(dataTestService.UnitOfWork, dataTestService.MapperCore, dataTestService.GetLogger<ClientTypesRepository>());
        await clientTypeRepository.CreateAsync(modelInput);

  // Act
    var result = await clientTypeRepository.GetAllClientTypesAsync();

    // Assert
    result.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedModel);
}

And finally this is my Mock class  :
public static class ClientTypeMock
 {
     public static ClientType GetClientType()
     {
         return new ClientType()
         {
             Id = 1,
             TypeName = "personne morale",
             Folders = new List<Folder>(),
             ClientTypeDocuments = new Collection<DocumentsToProvide>()
             {
                   new ()
                   {
                       DocumentName = "Attestation d’agriculteur",
                       DocumentDescription = "Attestation d’agriculteur",
                   },
             },
         };
     }
  public static IEnumerable<ClientType> GetAllClientType()
  {
      return new List<ClientType>()
  {
      new ClientType()
      {
          Id = 1,
          TypeName = "personne morale",
          Folders = new List<Folder>(),
          ClientTypeDocuments = new List<DocumentsToProvide>(),
      },
  };
  }
}

So can someone help me i'm realyy stucked ?
